# The specified module could not be found (MySQL)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake, rdoc

what to do for following error on windows:

```
C:\work\exchange2>gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.3.11)
actionpack (2.3.11)
activerecord (2.3.11)
activeresource (2.3.11)
activesupport (2.3.11)
mysql (2.8.1 x86-mingw32)
rack (1.1.2)
rails (2.3.11)
rake (0.9.2)
```

```
C:\work\exchange2>rake db:migrate
rake/rdoctask is deprecated.  Use rdoc/task instead (in RDoc 2.4.2+)
!!! The bundled mysql.rb driver has been removed from Rails 2.2. Please install
the mysql gem and try again: gem install mysql.
rake aborted!
126: The specified module could not be found.   - C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/g
ems/mysql-2.8.1-x86-mingw32/lib/1.8/mysql_api.so

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

**UPDATE2:**
Im using Mysql server 5.5,in which I found Libmql file in /lib directory,so I pasted that file in ruby/bin as well as in ruby/lib.
And on cmd I got the same above error.

**UPDATE1:** on again running this,I got :

> C:\work\exchange2>gem install mysql Successfully installed
>   mysql-2.8.1-x86-mingw32 1 gem installed Installing ri documentation
>   for mysql-2.8.1-x86-mingw32...
>
> No definition for next_result
>
> No definition for field_name
>
> No definition for field_table
>
> No definition for field_def
>
> No definition for field_type
>
> No definition for field_length
>
> No definition for field_max_length
>
> No definition for field_flags
>
> No definition for field_decimals
>
> No definition for time_inspect
>
> No definition for time_to_s
>
> No definition for time_get_year
>
> No definition for time_get_month
>
> No definition for time_get_day
>
> No definition for time_get_hour
>
> No definition for time_get_minute
>
> No definition for time_get_second
>
> No definition for time_get_neg
>
> No definition for time_get_second_part
>
> No definition for time_set_year
>
> No definition for time_set_month
>
> No definition for time_set_day
>
> No definition for time_set_hour
>
> No definition for time_set_minute
>
> No definition for time_set_second
>
> No definition for time_set_neg
>
> No definition for time_set_second_part
>
> No definition for time_equal
>
> No definition for error_errno
>
> No definition for error_sqlstate Installing RDoc documentation for
>   mysql-2.8.1-x86-mingw32...
>
> No definition for next_result
>
> No definition for field_name
>
> No definition for field_table
>
> No definition for field_def
>
> No definition for field_type
>
> No definition for field_length
>
> No definition for field_max_length
>
> No definition for field_flags
>
> No definition for field_decimals
>
> No definition for time_inspect
>
> No definition for time_to_s
>
> No definition for time_get_year
>
> No definition for time_get_month
>
> No definition for time_get_day
>
> No definition for time_get_hour
>
> No definition for time_get_minute
>
> No definition for time_get_second
>
> No definition for time_get_neg
>
> No definition for time_get_second_part
>
> No definition for time_set_year
>
> No definition for time_set_month
>
> No definition for time_set_day
>
> No definition for time_set_hour
>
> No definition for time_set_minute
>
> No definition for time_set_second
>
> No definition for time_set_neg
>
> No definition for time_set_second_part
>
> No definition for time_equal
>
> No definition for error_errno
>
> No definition for error_sqlstate

Comment: Try installing the mysql gem.

Answer (score 2):

You should try running `gem install mysql` which should clear the error message regarding this:

```
!!! The bundled mysql.rb driver has been removed from Rails 2.2. Please install
the mysql gem and try again: gem install mysql.
rake aborted!
126: The specified module could not be found.   - C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/g
ems/mysql-2.8.1-x86-mingw32/lib/1.8/mysql_api.so
```

The error regarding rdoc is a little harder to diagnose however I think it involves a few lines in your Rakefile, if you see some lines that resemble the following:

```
require 'rake/rdoctask'
Rake::RDocTask.new(:rdoc) do |rdoc|
```

Try changing them to resemble this:

```
require 'rdoc/task'
RDoc::Task.new do |rdoc|
```

Comment: Have you tried running the command again? Is there any abnormal output when you install the gem?

Comment: Also, if you have the mysql server installed locally at `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin` then you may want to copy the file `libmysql.dll` into `C:\Ruby187\bin`, and past any output you get in the question with code formatting so everyone can see it.

Comment: place that dll in this folder `C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/g
ems/mysql-2.8.1-x86-mingw32/lib/1.8/`

Comment: Since your using an older version of the gem try using a different dll http://instantrails.rubyforge.org/svn/trunk/InstantRails-win/InstantRails/mysql/bin/libmySQL.dll

Comment: @DevinM - Thanks for the tip about moving into the `C:\Ruby193\bin` folder, that fixed this problem for me!

Answer (score 1):

This problem happened to me before when I was trying to deploy on server and my problem was that I didn't set the **RAILS_ENV** environment variable.
so you can try to set it using:

```
set RAILS_ENV=production
```